# WCF Service Config File?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Can someone please help with how I configure my WCF service. The environment is IIS6 and the service can only be accessed via https (the firewall only allows connections to the server on port 443).

So, when I access https://myservice.com/Service.svc it gives me the URL of the WSDL file, which is the correct https address (I got this working by enabled httpsget, i think, there has been a lot of guess work!)

However, if I then consume the service, the end point address is http://localservername/Service.svc.

I assume I need to configure my web.config file to return the correct soap address, but having googled and read so many posts about endpoints, binding and behaviours, I am confused.

Can someone please clear this up for me, how do I configure my service to allow https connection and get the correct SOAP address?

Cheers

Chris

Comment: Can you post a sample of your web.config file so we can see how your endpoint is configured?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx

Quote the Note:
"Just one note: after 3 hours we realized that webHttpBinding is not suitable for regular SOAP-based clients (one has to watch these bindings :) We switched webHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding and our SOAP-based clients were able to parse the generated WSDL and to consume the web service."